Correct Interpretation of Apparent Charge Transfer Coefficients
Good day guys,
I was looking over some $i$ vs $\eta $ for a redox reaction. The main reaction taking place is:
$$\ce{N2 + 6 Li+ + 6 e- -> 2 Li3N}$$
Plotting the data and fitting the Tafel equation at large overpotentials:
$$\eta_c = \frac{RT}{\alpha_c F}\ln\left(\frac{i}{i_0}\right)$$
The fit showed great agreement with the curve. I noticed that the fit yielded apparent transfer coefficients of ~0.2 (slightly lower) for both cathodic and anodic reactions.
From the Butler-Volmer equation, I had understood that the apparent charge transfer coefficients were proportional to the symmetry factor $\beta$ and the number of transferred electrons $n$ in the following way:
$$\alpha_a = (1-\beta)n$$
and
$$\alpha_c = \beta n$$
However, the apparent transfer coefficients of my fit do not seem to agree with this interpretation. Since they do not add up to an integer number of electrons transferred.
Does that mean the Tafel plot does not always apply? or there is a different interpretation to the apparent charge transfer coefficents?

What is the reactions you are looking at ? The values depend on the mechanism.
To measure charge transfer coefficients, you must avoid diffusion control. I would also correct carefully uncompensated resistance, as a matter of good practice.

For uncompensated resistance, should I just correct it via:  $\eta_{corrected} = \eta + I*R_u$ ? I have also added the reaction to the question, thank you for your feedback, best regards.

I am not sure that people compensate for resistance for plating experiments, since you modify the electrode and it electronic conductivity during your reaction. Anyway, here is a paper that I find useful on the subject:

Zheng, W. iR Compensation for Electrocatalysis Studies: Considerations and Recommendations. ACS Energy Lett. 2023, 8 (4), 1952–1958. [https://doi.org/10.1021/acsenergylett.3c00366]


Remember, that the Tafel slope always assumes ONE transferred electron only, because the rate-determining step of an electrochemical reaction transfers only one; the overall current is then 6 transferred electrons

Thank you very much for your insight. I am slightly confused as the there are versions of the BV equation that include the number of electrons $n$ and reduces to the Tafel equation at high overpotentials. The book that I have been using the most is "Electrochemistry" by Hamann, Hamnett and Vielstich

I do not know all the details on exactly how the reaction is run so I am assuming that you start from a clean inert electrode (or a pure Li electrode) with Li+ and N2 dissolved in the electrolyte.
The reaction you describe is not a pure electrochemical reaction, you have:

plating/stripping or intercalation/deintercalation of Li, which is an electrochemical step
nitridation of Li to form Li3N, which is not an electrochemical step.

The chemical step (2) will not result in a net flow of charges in your cell and it is not clear how it would depend on the potential of the electrode (if it does at all).
The electrode is different during plating and stripping/deintercalation: no nitride at first but stripping/deintercalation happen from a nitrided electrode. The environment of Li is different. Because of that, I would not expect that the charge transfer coefficients have a simple relationship.
You should probably read on Lithium plating to see what is the expected behaviour in your electrolyte. There is decomposition of the electrolyte at the plating potential of Li pretty much all the time.
